# Fine to cut a git branch from soon to be deleted branch?

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

Is there any foreseeable trouble in cutting a branch (`B`) from another branch (`A`) that will be merged and deleted? That is `A` will be merged to master and deleted prior to `B`'s merging and deleting. Do I need to keep branch `A` around until `B` is finished or is it safe to delete?

```
master ----------------------------
             |
             |
             A---------------------
                    |
                    |
                    B--------------
```

Comment: just verified, this is happy stuff in git. However this can trip up any open PRs in github that are based on branch `A`. https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/361. Such PRs will be closed by github, I'll have to make a mental note to edit my PRs to change the base to the `master` or whatever the desired upstream branch was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, there's absolutely no problem in this. Remember that the commit where B branched from will not go anywhere when you merge A to master:

```
master ------*--*-------*------*------*------*
             |                       /^
             |                      / |____Merged A to master
             -------*-------*------/
                    |
                    |
                    B----------*---------*
```

And even if you would do a squash merge, it wouldn't do any harm. When you eventually merge B to master only the changes B has then compared to master are relevant, the point where B originated from makes no difference.

Answer (score 2):

In git, tags and branches are references that enable you to get to an item in a directed graph. The only graph paths to the roots that are available are those that end in branches or tags. Without a branch or a tag (or a reference that's neither, like a detached HEAD), you have nothing.

The fact that there even is a branch A is mostly irrelevant from the point of view of branch B: it only matters for tracking merges, and in no case would lack of branch A lose anything other than such information. Since branch A will be merged and closed (removed), whatever tracking information you wanted is already applied to `master` at the point of merging. If you merge B, it'll happen later, and B already carries the path from itself, through the fragment of branch A, to the roots of the graph (there may be many!).

If branch A was removed without merging it, branch B would look like a straight line to master: it'd include the commits from branch A on the path from B to a most recent common ancestor commit on the master branch.

What matters is that you have some handle for branch B, and you do: the branch itself is the handle. You could also have a tag (tags and branches are identical in all ways other than their interpretation during merges and conflict solving). Or a detached HEAD. Or live on the edge and keep the only live reference in the recycle bin (a.k.a. a head with no references that's kept around until it expires and gets garbage collected).